# How to insert Expr when using VisitMut?

Tags: rust, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently using [syn](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/index.html) following an example to create an AST that can be mutated. I understand that I can modify the node I'm travesing (as shown below in my current code) but
I'm curious if I can add some code in between the current node and the next node. Is the syn crate capable of this?

```rs
use syn::visit_mut::{self, VisitMut};
use syn::Expr;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

impl VisitMut for MyStruct {
    fn visit_expr_mut(&mut self, node: &mut Expr) {
        if let Expr::MethodCall(expr) = &node.to_owned() {
            // I can modify the existing node like so:
            *node = parse_quote!("// Hello World");
            
            // How could I add something after this node and before the next?
        }
    }
}

pub fn create() {
    let current_dir = std::env::current_dir().expect("Unable to get current directory");
    let rust_file = std::fs::read_to_string(current_dir.join("src").join("lib.rs")).expect("Unable to read rust file");
    let ast = syn::parse_file(&rust_file).expect("Unable to create AST from rust file");

    MyStruct.visit_file_mut(&mut ast);
}
```

**Edit to show use case:**

The file I'm currently parsing looks like:

```rs
#[macro_use]
extern crate foo;
mod test;
fn init(handle: foo::InitHandle) {
    handle.add_class::<Test::test>();
}
```

Let's say that when I read the AST, I want to add another mod and another handle for it like so:

```rs
#[macro_use]
extern crate foo;
mod test;
mod store;
fn init(handle: foo::InitHandle) {
    handle.add_class::<Test::test>();
    handle.add_class::<Store::store>();
}
```

Comment: That highly depends on what you want to _add_. Could you give an/some example(s) of input and desired output?

Comment: @vallentin I edited the question to show my desired use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, it highly depends on what you want to *insert*. Because you can't just insert anything before or after `node` easily.

For your specific case, you could use [`parse_quote!`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/macro.parse_quote.html) to produce an [`ExprBlock`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/struct.ExprBlock.html).

```rust
*node = parse_quote!(
    {
        #expr;
        handle.add_class::<Store::store>();
    }
);
```

Which with the following input:

```rust
fn init(handle: foo::InitHandle) {
    handle.add_class::<Test::test>();
}
```

Would produce this output:

```rust
fn init(handle: foo::InitHandle) {
    {
        handle.add_class::<Test::test>();
        handle.add_class::<Store::store>();
    };
}
```

*(Note I have reformatted the output, to be prettier)*

---

Alternatively, you could *override* [`visit_block_mut()`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/visit_mut/trait.VisitMut.html#method.visit_block_mut) instead. That way you'd have access to [`stmts: Vec<Stmt>`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/struct.Block.html#structfield.stmts), and would be able to insert before and after a [`Stmt`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/enum.Stmt.html). The **downside** is that by doing it that way, you wouldn't be able to easily visit all [`Expr`s](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/enum.Expr.html), as by using [`visit_expr_mut()`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.58/syn/visit_mut/trait.VisitMut.html#method.visit_expr_mut).